# NOt able to get the app secret for Facebook login with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, facebook-login, app-secret

I have explored all the options in my app console page in facebook developers site. Nowhere I am able to find secret key which is required to use facebook login with firebase.  Looking at other solutions.. they says it is found on dashboard, but on my dashboard it is nowhere.. How can i get this app secret please  help..

[image: This is the Screenshot of the console developers page]

Is it the same as client token provided..

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Go to the settings tab then click on basic, on the right side there is a label "App Secret", click on show and enter your password and then you will find your app secret.

Comment: Actually it was a updated version of console..that's why I was unable to find it.  Anyway Thanks for help..

Comment: Hey, can u provide me ur personal email ID. I just want to have some conversation with you. If, there is no problem in it.

Comment: Thank you very much!! every where have written that the app_secret is on the FB app dashboard!!!

Comment: GENIUS... thanks so much because there was like NO indication on where to get the secret... bad UX imo

Answer (score 1):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/facebook-login
Go to https://developers.facebook.com/ click on myapps
click on app which is shown below image :
[image]

and inside it click on dropdown on setting as shown in below image:
[image]

click on secret password it will ask to add password of facebook add it and copied it.
cheeers !!!

Answer (score 0):

gotto settings on facebook development site. then hit basic. you will see your app secret.

you maybe prompted to enter your fb password.

hope this helps.

Frank